# How to set the scope for a customized widget in SonarQube?

Tags: widget, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

I created a custom widget in Sonar to show some data for a particular project. There are 3 projects in the list and only one of them should display this widget.

I tried setting the Widget Scope `@WidgetScope(value = PROJECT)`. Also tried not setting anything as default scope is supposed to be `Project`.

I'm using v5.1.2 SonarQube.

But it still shows up on all the projects with the same data.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import org.sonar.api.web.AbstractRubyTemplate;
import org.sonar.api.web.Description;
import org.sonar.api.web.RubyRailsWidget;
import org.sonar.api.web.UserRole;
import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetCategory;
import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetProperties;
import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetProperty;
import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetPropertyType;
import org.sonar.api.web.WidgetScope;
import org.sonar.api.resources.Project;
import static org.sonar.api.web.WidgetScope.PROJECT;


@UserRole(UserRole.USER)
@Description("An Internal Plugin to display some data in  a project")
@WidgetCategory("some-data Plugin")
@WidgetScope(value = PROJECT)
@WidgetProperties({
  @WidgetProperty(key = "Index",type=WidgetPropertyType.STRING
  ),
})
public class OneMoreRubyWidget extends AbstractRubyTemplate implements RubyRailsWidget {

  @Override
  public String getId() {
    return "SomeData";
  }

  @Override
  public String getTitle() {
    return "SomeData";
  }

  protected String getTemplatePath() {
          return "/example/somedata.html.erb";  

  }
}
```

Is there any way I can get the "project name" from the Sonar Dashboard so that I can return different values in the widget for different projects?

Comment: Can you show the code of somedata.html.erb? If you want to hide the widget for some conditions, you have to make changes there.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to suppress display of the widget when there's no relevant data, then store data only for relevant projects.

Several widgets do conditional display already. Take a look at [this Widget Lab widget](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-widget-lab/blob/master/src/main/resources/measure_bar_chart_widget.html.erb#L26) which makes display conditional.